# How to draw dots on a UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer

I already have a view controller with a default view and few things added to it programmatically.
Now I have a draggable shape which I can move and whenever I click a button a dot should be drawn there at a point I want.

Now My UIView is not a custom view so I cant use drawRect.

So I have two solutions use CALayer or to use small images for dots or a small custom view that represents a dot.

Which will be a better solution or If there is a simpler way then please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CALayer is better and faster in your case. Just don't forget to `setShouldRasterize:YES` to your view's layer.